# Elasticsearch how to display all records but the search criteria only applied to calculate score

Tags: elasticsearch

in Elasticsearch how do i display all records but the search criteria only applied to calculate score

for e.g the document has field city(text) if i search city "New York" then it should display all the records but the documents with the city "New Your" should have high score.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a `match_all` as an OR condition with your query. Like this:

```
GET index/type/_search?pretty
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match_all": {}
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "field": "text"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In that case, it would be nice if you accept the answer.